# What is this grassy houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have this type of grassy houseplant. I think it might be a Ponytail Palm, but it seems to be slightly different. I want to put them outside on the porch my cats frequent, but they go crazy chomping at them so I'm afraid they will get sick. I need to identify the plant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited the photos into the post for you. Please ask a separate question for your other plant. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This plant looks like a **pencil cactus** or **milkbush**.   If that is a pencil cactus, the plant is toxic to dogs and cats.  If a person contacts the white, milky, latex sap of the plant, it can cause an anaphylactic reaction.
Please do not let your cats, or any pet, chew on this plant.

[Pencil Cactus](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/toxic-and-non-toxic-plants/pencil-cactus)